# VS Code + Node.js + Prettier auto-formatting messing up the dictionary key

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, prettier

I am using VS Code for my Node.js development. I've installed the Prettier - Code formatter and here are my settings.

```
{
    "code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "/usr/bin/python3",
    },
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    },
    "prettier.trailingComma": "es5",
}
```

If I enable the editor.formatOnSave setting in the editor which is set to true for javascript with the defaultFormatter set to prettier, it is messing up a dictionary that I am initializing.

Before saving, this is what my dictionary looks like (**authorization** within double quotes):

```
const blendConnection = {
    hostname: "api.beta.blendlabs.com",
    port: 443,
    path: "/home-lending/applications",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Length": loanData.length,
        "blend-target-instance": blendTargetInstance,
        "blend-api-version": blendApiVersion,
        "authorization": blendAuthorization,
    },
};
```

But after saving or formatting the file with prettier, the quotes are removed from **authorization** part in the dictionary which is messing up my code.

```
const blendConnection = {
    hostname: "api.beta.blendlabs.com",
    port: 443,
    path: "/home-lending/applications",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Length": loanData.length,
        "blend-target-instance": blendTargetInstance,
        "blend-api-version": blendApiVersion,
        authorization: blendAuthorization,
    },
};
```

Any suggestions why this may be happening with the prettier formatting? Is this a bug or is authorization a keyword that the extension is fixing it in the way it should be. I am using this dictionary to initialize headers for a HTTP request so any suggestions how I can either fix the formatting with prettier or initialize the headers would be useful.

Comment: JS has no "dictionaries", it has objects. Having said that: this is fine? JS object properties _do not need quotes_ except when the property name needs to contain normally invalid characters, like spaces, or dashes, etc. The two objects you show are identical as far as JS is concerned, the interpereter doens't care, the JIT doesn't care, and so if you use prettier, you should also just not care: prettier wrote 100% syntactically correct JS code to your file, so all is well.

Comment: Hey @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - thanks so much. I am new to JavaScript and Node.js so this was great to know. I executed my code and it worked fine. Appreciate the knowledge share.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up .prettierignore to ignore that file, so it won't format it. Here's the link to the official doc : https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).